# CSS doesn't get applied onto div's while they are in EditForm - Blazor

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

I have a Problem where my CSS Code does not get applied to div's that are located inside an EditForm.

I am using a Template from some Bootstrap Template Site and I have defined what CSS Stylesheet my Website should use.
My Problem: When I put my div's inside an EntryForm the CSS does not get applied to those div's.
Outside the EntryForm everything get's styled like it should.

There is no EditForm Tag inside any of the CSS Files that could possibly overwrite the CSS Markup for the div's.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem yesterday, though it could be from a different cause.
Try commenting out the code that instantiates the component and see if you find a different error that is being masked.
Also it would be useful to know if itellisense lists the class names you are using or not.

Comment: Already fixed, I just implemented some new tags and id's. But thank you for commenting.